# OpenLayers marker rotation

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openstreetmap

How can I rotate the marker with OpenLayers. I need it to be dynamic rather then static:

This is my code in component.ts file

```
var size = new OpenLayers.Size(30, 30);
   var offset = new OpenLayers.Pixel(-(size.w ), -size.h);
   var icon = new OpenLayers.Icon('ship.PNG', size, offset);
   var zoom = 3;
   var fromProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");   // Transform from WGS 1984
   var toProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"); // to Spherical Mercator Projection
   var  map = new OpenLayers.Map("map");
    map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM());

    var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat( -0.1279688 ,51.5077286 )
          .transform(
            new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), // transform from WGS 1984
            map.getProjectionObject() // to Spherical Mercator Projection
          );



    var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Markers" );
    map.addLayer(markers);

    map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(3, 56.1122).transform(fromProjection, toProjection), zoom);

    /* var angle = 30;
    function _rotate() {
      markers.setIconAngle(angle);
      angle = (angle + 10) % 360;
      setTimeout(_rotate, 1000);
    }
    _rotate(); */

    markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(lonLat));
```

Comment: Hey @scai can you help me out in this?

Comment: Did you check the answers for this similar question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/25983417/1340631

Comment: Yes, but I am afraid, it's not working out.